# Visual studio UWP как скруглить края у Border только с 1 стороны?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Имеется Border при использовании свойства Corner Radius закругляются сразу 4 угла. Как быть если мне необходимо закруглить только сверху?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы задать скругление у верхнего правого угла, вам необходимо воспользоваться свойством `CornerRadius`. Важно понимать, что данное свойство может содержать не одно значение, а несколько.

Если указать сразу 4 цифры, как в данном случае, то `первая цифра` в значении  будет означать `верхний левый угол`, `вторая цифра` - `верхний правый угол`, `третья цифра` - `нижний правый угол`, `четвертая цифра` - `нижний левый угол`.
Пример ниже, задает скругление у верхнего левого угла.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10 0 0 0">
        <Button>Кнопка</Button>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Свойство [`CornerRadius`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.border#properties_) имеет тип не `double`, а [`CornerRadius`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.cornerradius), и позволяет задавать индивидуальные значения по каждому из углов. Синтаксис:

```
<Border CornerRadius="topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft"/>
```

Для вашего случая, например

```
<Border CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"/>
```